# Perl: How can I call object methods inside END {} without warning?

Tags: perl, perl-module

```
package JustTesting;
use strict;
use warnings;

sub new {
    my $self = {};
    bless($self, shift);
    END { $self->goodbye() };
    return $self;
}

sub goodbye {
    print "Goodbye.\n";
}

package main;
my $this = JustTesting->new();
```

**Output:**

> Variable "$self" will not stay shared at ./test line 10.
>   Goodbye.

Apparently it works and I can suppress the warning with `no
warnings` inside the END block. But I wonder if there is a better way
how to do this.

I tried using an anonymous sub like this:

```
my $cleanup = sub { $self->goodbye() };
END { $cleanup->() };
```

and then like this:

```
END { sub { $self->goodbye() }->() };
```

But I always get the same warning.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You most likely want [`DESTROY`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlobj.html#Destructors) instead of `END`. See also [the section on destructors in perltoot](http://perldoc.perl.org/perltoot.html#Destructors).

```
package JustTesting;
use strict;
use warnings;

sub new {
    my $self = {};
    bless($self, shift);
    return $self;
}

sub goodbye {
    print "Goodbye.\n";
}

sub DESTROY {
    my ($self) = @_;
    $self->goodbye()
};


package main;
{
    say "entering scope";
    my $this = JustTesting->new();
    say "leaving scope";
}
say "left scope";
```

Output:

```
entering scope
leaving scope
Goodbye.
left scope
```

Comment: Yup, that's what I was looking for. Thanks! Now I should probably go off and buy a book about object-oriented design methodology, and bang my forehead with it for the next six months or so.

Answer (score 8):

Just for reference to future readers I've attached a [`Moose`](http://moose.perl.org) version of [daxim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/46395/daxim)'s correct [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1914730/perl-how-can-i-call-object-methods-inside-end-without-warning/1914817#1914817).

```
use 5.012;
use warnings;

{
    package JustTesting;
    use Moose;
    use namespace::clean -except => 'meta';

    sub goodbye { say "Goodbye." }

    sub DEMOLISH {
        my ($self) = @_;
        $self->goodbye;
    }
}

{
    say "entering scope";
    my $this = JustTesting->new();
    say "leaving scope"; 
}

say "left scope";
```

Note the use of the `DEMOLISH` subroutine for the [destructor](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Moose/lib/Moose/Manual/Concepts.pod#Destructor).

NB. You will find that DESTROY still works but DEMOLISH is the correct Moosey way of doing it.

/I3az/

Answer (score 4):

First, see [`my()` Scoped Variable in Nested Subroutines](http://www.perl.com/pub/a/2002/05/07/mod_perl.html#my%28%29%20scoped%20variable%20in%20nested%20subroutines) for an explanation.

Second, I think you should either use [`DESTROY`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlobj#Destructors) or a helper class depending on what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 3):

The reason for the warning is because even though it doesn't look like it, to perl an `END` block is equivalent to the declaration of a regular (named) sub, and the behavior of a named sub declared inside of another sub isn't what you want -- `$self` inside the `END` block will be bound to `$self` in `sub new` the *first* time that `new` is called, and it will continue to see that same value -- the very first instance created -- for the rest of the life of your program. The first instance will have a reference held by the `END` block and won't be destroyed until the end of the program, and any later instances won't have that `END` block called on them at all.

Unlike named subs, anonymous subs don't have this problem because they're re-constructed every time their definition is encountered, so any variables they close over are bound as late as possible, and the values you actually want are captured.

This is a pretty long explanation when others have already told you that what you want is `DESTROY` instead, but I thought you might like to know what's *actually* happening with the code you wrote.

Answer (score 1):

By the time the `END` block is called, $cleanup has already been deallocated. To do any work with a variable, you should use a destructor instead.

See "destructors" at [perldoc perlobj](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlobj#Destructors).