# Execute some code always before the Perl script ends

Tags: perl

How can I set a code that must execute before a Perl script stops?

In here [how to run piece of code just before the exit of perl script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3078508/how-to-run-piece-of-code-just-before-the-exit-of-perl-script) I read about the END subroutine, but it only executes if the script ends normally. However, I want the code to be executed also if, for example, user aborts the program by ^C.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Trap the termination signals and re-route them so something, simplest would be:

```
$SIG{TERM} = $SIG{INT} = $SIG{QUIT} = $SIG{HUP} = sub { die; };
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked. Only I got that assigned subroutine executed three times after ^C signal...

Comment: @Janis so, now you know, that ^C signal is a 3 different signals ;) maybe you want to use only one signal, like `QUIT` or `TERM` or `INT`. re-route only one of them.

Comment: Or you could have the `sub` remember that it was already called. The [`state`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/state.html) keyword might be good for that.

Comment: Lawks! What operating system sends 3 signals for a ^C?