# Perl: How to move a file when a script exits

Tags: perl

I have a Perl script that's running. When it finished, a log file is moved from one directory to another. However, when the script is running and it is exited via `ctrl C`, the log is not moved. So, the next time the script finishes and the log will contain the info from the 1st unfinished run and the 2nd finished run. The pseudo code:

```
$SIG{INT} = \&catchSignal;
$SIG{TERM} = \&catchSignal;

sub catchSignal
{
    print " We are exiting \n";
    exit;
}


sub mainFuction()
{
    # Does a bunch of stuff
    .
    .
    .
    rotateLog()
}

sub rotateLog()
{
    # Moves the log from dir1 to dir2
}
```

I'm wondering how to rotate that log (in Perl) when the script exits, whether from a `ctrl C` or the finishing of the script.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3078508/how-to-run-piece-of-code-just-before-the-exit-of-perl-script

Comment: @Robert thanks for the reference. I placed an END block in the script (not in any subroutine), and it does not execute when I ctrl C out of the script.

Comment: Read the other answers in the linked question as well. You need to handle the signal from Ctrl+C: `$SIG{TERM} = \&signal_handler;`

Comment: I have the signal_handler, but it's not catching it. I'm printing some text, and I'm not seeing that text from a ctrl C

Comment: Can you show a minimal complete example of the problem?  A signal handler should be it.

Comment: @zdim I added the signal handler code. The rest of the code itself is very complex so I thought pseudo code would make it easier. In this particular case, I don't think the actual code is important, but please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Thank you -- yes, that should be fine.  And ... that should work.  Does this run in a terminal?  (In your "real" signal handler you have more done, yes? Things that you'd see regardless of how the program runs?)  Can it be that the handler fires just fine but that log-rotation doesn't work correctly (out of the handler)?  Add something yet else to it -- like writing a silly file in your home directory (you should have permissions for that?).

Comment: Can you check (for fact) what signal Ctrl-C sends on your system?

Comment: Does this run over a network of some sort -- can it be that Ctrl-C is killing some connection (thus the Broken pipe` you mention in another comment)? You have to give us more detail -- again, can you reduce that complex program to a few lines that still show the problem?

Comment: Any reason not to call 'rotateLogs' from the signal handling `catchSignal` ? Any problem with logRotation during normal exit ? Do you have to cover exit by 'die'-ing ?